# Error Undefined index: dashboard_id.name when loading Dashboard

Tags: error, dashboard

Users reported to me today that the dashboard wasn't displaying on our Drupal 7 CiviCRM installation. Not sure how long this has been going on as we're all volunteers in a small charity so it's not looked at every day but could easily be a week or more. I'd not updated anything in the past month or so, so after trying different broswers, clearing the caches etc. didn't help I upgraded to latest versions of everything (Drupal 7.52 / Civicrm 4.7.13) but that has not fixed it. Whenever I access the dashboard I get a message in the Drupal log saying:

Notice: Undefined index: dashboard_id.name in CRM_Core_BAO_Dashboard::getContactDashlets() (line 133 of [server folder]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/Dashboard.php).

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is also happening in Wordpress installation of CiviCRM. Choosing "Membership Dashboard" from left hand menu (in Wordpress Dashboard) as super admin (should have all permissions) All that is displayed is the CiviCRM Resources panel. Using Wordpress 4.7.2 with CiviCRM 4.7.14. Adding ini_set('display_errors',1); to civicrm.settings.php produces a CiviCRM Notice of: Notice: Undefined index: dashboard_id.name in {server location}/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/Dashboard.php on line 133 Upon further investigation, I checked the database table being queried on this line. Table i